# AS3 XML problem

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript

My Flash project is made of several .swf files, one of them loads XML gallery. everything works fine on my machine, but when I upload it to the testing server gallery content doesn't load.

All my paths are relative to Main swf file. I can't makeabsolute URLs, b/c I have to deliver "working" zip package.

What could be wrong?

edit:

When preloading on testing server on mac I get (IO errorError Event- load never completed) on FF and Chrome. But 0 errors on pc.

Comment: Can you access XML file with your browser after it is uploaded to testing server?

Comment: Yes, I can access the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

could it simply be the OS specific path-seperators or case-sensitivity?

if you delimit folders by "/" then it works on all OSs, but if you use "\" it might actually work on windows only. also, please note that virtually all Linux/UNIX file systems are case sensitive, whereas for windows it's the other way round. so while windows ignores different character case, on a Linux/UNIX machine, the file just won't be found.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing the app locally inside a browser or inside the Flash IDE?

Check if your app can access files on the network. When you test using the browser on your machine, the SWF runs inside a local sandbox. You can't access local files and files on the network at the same time. It might be the case that your SWF is configured to access only local files.

The 'Activity' window in Safari is helpful in cases like this. See if it shows the correct XML URL when you load the SWF from your server.